# How to write UnitTest in MOQ for SendEmail method parameters in C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have the below method in C#. How do I write unit tests for the parameters with Moq?. I wanted to make sure the email sender address, cc, emailbody, senderaccountpassword are correct

Not sure what to mock and what should be the object.

```
public string SendEmail(string emailNotificationSender, string senderAccountPassword, string emailCcList,
    string emailBody, string emailSubject, List<string> toReceipients)
{
    try
    {
        ExchangeService exchangeService = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2016);
        exchangeService.Credentials = new WebCredentials(emailNotificationSender, senderAccountPassword);
        exchangeService.AutodiscoverUrl(emailNotificationSender, RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);
        EmailMessage email = new EmailMessage(exchangeService);
        email.ToRecipients.AddRange(toReceipients);
        List<string> EmailNotificationCcList = new List<string>();
        EmailNotificationCcList = emailCcList.Split(';').ToList();
        email.CcRecipients.AddRange(EmailNotificationCcList);
        email.Subject = emailSubject;
        email.Body = new MessageBody(emailBody.ToString());
        email.Send();

        //return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult("Success");
        return "Success";

    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        OnError(new ErrorRecordEventArgs
        {
            ErrorSource = "ExchangeDataStore::ExecuteQuery()",
            //DataSource = dataSource,
            //DataSourceType = dataSourceType,
            Exception = exception
        });
    }
    return default;
}
```

```
public static bool RedirectionUrlValidationCallback(string redirectionUrl)
{
    // The default for the validation callback is to reject the URL.
    bool result = false;
    Uri redirectionUri = new Uri(redirectionUrl);
    // Validate the contents of the redirection URL. In this simple validation
    // callback, the redirection URL is considered valid if it is using HTTPS
    // to encrypt the authentication credentials. 
    if (redirectionUri.Scheme == "https")
    {
        result = true;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: If you're trying to test `SendEmail()`, you don't want to mock that, but any of its dependencies. So you don't have to actually send an email, for instance. In which case you'd need to restructure your code so that you can easily replace the service dependency with the mock you set up for a test.

Comment: Thanks Jasen, i want to write mock test for SendEmail() parameters are correct. such as emailNotificationSender, senderAccountPassword, emailCcList,
             emailBody, emailSubject, List<string> toReceipients. let me know how do i write that

Comment: _"i wanted to make sure the email sender address,cc,emailbody,senderaccountpasswork are correct"_ Are you testing _your_ code, or the framework's `EmailMessage`? If you want to test `EmailMessage`, put it in its own test and plug in your variables (seems pointless though).